# linq xml error handling

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i hope this is a simple question!

in the following code all is well if the element exists but if not it errors out.
            XDocument xmldoc = new XDocument();

```
        xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(response);


        XElement errorNode = xmldoc.Root.Element("TransactionErrorCode").Element("Code");
```

How can i test to see if it exists so it doesnt trow an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you getting a NullReferenceException?

Test to see if the first element exists before you try to work with it:

```
var transactionErrorCode = xmldoc.Root.Element("TransactionErrorCode");
if(transactionErrorCode != null)
{
    var code= transactionErrorCode .Element("Code");
}
```

Comment: thanks but the root element is only there sometimes! and this results in 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have tried is empty but get the same problem...

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry just read and tried that again!

It works great.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
if (xmlDoc != null)
{
  root = xmlDoc.Root;
  if (xmldoc.Root != null)
  {
   ... You get the idea

  }
}
```